# How to Retrieve Post ID and custom field of previously Visited WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several post which would redirect to a  *thank you* page.
In my *thank you* page, I want to retrieve the previously or last visited `post_id` so I can retrieve the custom fields  value of the `post_id`  to make my condition work.

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$tags= get_field('product_tags', $postid);

if(tags == 'action'  &&  !is_user_logged_in()) {    

        echo 'Not For you';
}

else {
echo 'Welcome';
}
```

The result would be like :

You have accessed **"last post visited post title"** that is under **"custom fields"**

Answer (score 0):

We have some options to do that.

1) You can find the post id using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. You can find the post_id by the slug of the previous page which you can get from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] .

2) When redirecting to Thank you page. you can include the post id in the query string. Something like,

> wp_redirect(site_url('thankyou?id='.$post->ID));
>   exit;

Or if you are using javascript for redirect you can achieve the result similarly.

Hope it helps.